# 'View Details' missing from exception assistant

Tags: visual-studio

Recently the behavior of the exception assistant changed for me in visual studio 2015 update 3. I no longer see the 'View Details' option and the stack trace does not get unwound. If I select 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode' it works. This happens on all C# projects.

The other thing is if I look at the 'Just-In-Time' option under the Debugging option. I see a warning saying 'Just-In-Time debugging registration errors detected'.

Changing the settings for the JIT debugging options didn't help. I also tried  refreshing the settings, repairing and I even reinstalling Visual studio. Nothing seems to help.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: It is not specific to Update 3, all releases of VS2015 have this problem.  It is a crappy bug, one among many, this shipped long before it was done.  Forcing the old debugging engine to be used with "Managed Compatibility Mode" is a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" in Debug -> Options