# "View Details " missing form Exception handler VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, exceptionhandler

This could easily be the same as:
['View Details' missing from exception assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213820/view-details-missing-from-exception-assistant)

But I am seeing it in VS 2017. Flipping "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" doesn't seem to make a difference.

This is what the window looks like:
[image]

With "View Details" missing, copy details only gives me the top level exception too.

If I wrap the code in a "try", "catch" block and use the debugger/immediate window to expand the exception object I can see important details like "inner exception". So why is this information hidden from me in the handler?

### **Additional Details**

I am working on a **Xamarin** project and this error was located in a property called from a .net core portable library, the error in this case, was to do with **NLog** (a third party nuget package) that was installed in both the library and the andorid project but was possibly failing due to bad config. The exception was raised when remote debugging on an **Android** device.

I have seen this issue with the exception handler in all exceptions I have had so far (3 / 4, its a new machine)

Comment: Raised as bug through visual studio feedback... https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/45537/view-exception-missing-from-exception-handler.html

Comment: this bug has now been fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and has been fixed